# buffering an audio file in android and playing specific bytes

Tags: android

I am working on an android application.
I have an audio file. I want to buffer it first and then read the specific bytes only and want to store them in another buffer and then play the second buffer.

My goal is to combine some specific words from audio file and then playing them altogether.
I will pass the 'to' and 'from' parameters(type String) to the play() method for buffering. Format of 'to' and 'from' will be like hh:mm:ss:ms.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Anupam

Comment: So, what's the question? How to store audio data or how to play or combine it?

Comment: problem is how to store audio in buffer and then combining some letters from this file on the basis of starting and end positions given...